# Dimensionality reduction techniques for uncorrelated feature without the target for regression?

Tags: python, dimensionality-reduction

I have this dataset 1356 x 12 and want to reduce the # of features to 8 - 10. I tried PCA but the variance capture is low. Any recommend techiques?

Comment: what do you want to do subsequently with these new features?

Comment: I'm gonna use it to input an ML model.